# How to add a number to a var every second

Tags: javascript, html

As a beginner in Javascript, I'm trying to make a clicker game. I don't know how to add a number to a var every second

Below is the code at the moment. I'm not sure how to make one of my "dank miners" automatically add coins every second to the player. Let's say there are two auto miners, then the player earns 4 coins per second. Also how to display how much the player is automatically making.

Thanks!

```js
let borkCoins = 0;

let dankMiner = 0;

const earnBork = () => {
  borkCoins += 1;
  displayScreen();
};

const buydankMiner1 = () => {

  if (borkCoins >= 20) {
    dankMiner += 1;
    borkCoins -= 20;
    displayScreen();
  } else {
    alert("Insufficient funds!")
  }
};

const displayScreen = () => {
  document.getElementById("bork-coins").innerText =
    borkCoins;
  document.getElementById("dankMiner").innerText =
    dankMiner;
};

displayScreen();
```

```html
<h3>Your BorkCoins: <span id="bork-coins"></h3>

<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/ef/6a/cf/ef6acfc481b76637b71d4a71db7de82a--dog-birthday-animal-memes.jpg"
    height="80" width="80" id="bork-coins" onclick="earnBork();">
    
      <p>Click on Gabe the Doggo to earn a BorkCoin!</p>
      
       <h3>Shop</h3>
       
       <p>Dank Miner <i>(2 BorkCoins/sec)</i>
    <br>Your Dank Miner(s): <span id="dankMiner"></span></p>
  <button id="dank-miner" onclick="buydankMiner1();">Buy 1 (20 BorkCoins)</button>
```

Comment: Try setTimeOut ? https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: Or setInterval https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an interval that checks for the number of miners:

```
setInterval(() => {
  if (dankMiner > 0) {
    borkCoins += dankMiner;
    displayScreen();
  }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) function and do something like this :

```js
let borkCoins = 0;
let dankMiner = 0;

const earnBork = () => {
  borkCoins += 1;
  displayScreen();
};

/* Code Added */
setInterval(earnBork, 1000);
/*--*/

const buydankMiner1 = () => {
  if (borkCoins >= 20) {
    dankMiner += 1;
    borkCoins -= 20;
    displayScreen();
  } else {
    alert("Insufficient funds!")
  }
};

const displayScreen = () => {
  document.getElementById("bork-coins").innerText =
    borkCoins;
  document.getElementById("dankMiner").innerText =
    dankMiner;
};

displayScreen();
```

```html
<h3>Your BorkCoins: <span id="bork-coins"></span></h3>
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/ef/6a/cf/ef6acfc481b76637b71d4a71db7de82a--dog-birthday-animal-memes.jpg" height="80" width="80" id="bork-coins" onclick="earnBork();">
<p>Click on Gabe the Doggo to earn a BorkCoin!</p>
<h3>Shop</h3>
<p>Dank Miner <i>(2 BorkCoins/sec)</i>
  <br>Your Dank Miner(s): <span id="dankMiner"></span></p>
<button id="dank-miner" onclick="buydankMiner1();">Buy 1 (20 BorkCoins)</button>
```